# How to identify database scheme changes in EF5

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-5

I developed a program that runs in production.
The program uses `EF5 Database First` for database access (read only).

I would like to display an error if the `.edmx` scheme is different than the database scheme of the database configured in the connetion string.

Query example:

`db.FirstTable.Where(x => x.Age> 4)`
If `Age` is for some reasond changed to `PersonAge` (due to database version mismatch), I want to fail safe.

Currently, I wait until the actual query occur (can be hours after the program is up), and then I handle the exception (`No such column "Age"...`).

I can try and call `db.TableX.first()` and look for the exception in the start up of the binary, is there more elegant way to validate scheme against the database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may well have a challenge. While [calling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

```
MyDbContext.Database.CompatibleWithModel(throwIfNoMetadata)
```

in EF5 looks like it would provide you with the information, the [EF V6 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.compatiblewithmodel%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) of the documentation includes this note:

> If the context was created using either the Model First or Database First approach then the model is assumed to be compatible with the database and this method returns true

I cannot recall any of the EF6 change logs indicating a change in this area (this does not mean there wasn't one), so it is not clear whether this is better documentation or a real behaviour change.

Some debugging with the [EF source](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) is probably necessary: however EF was only made open source after V5 was released.

EDIT: Additional. Looking at the *first* version of [`System.Data.Entity.Database`](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1dc675f86d6c22a9f59b1085e07c08bb7c5063c2#src/EntityFramework/Database.cs) its XML doc comment include the above quote.

Comment: You are right, when calling `CompatibleWithModel` on the DB first context it throws - `. DbContext instances created from an ObjectContext or using an EDMX file cannot be checked for compatibility`